# Javascript private variables and parameters have same name

Tags: javascript

```
function() {
  var name;
  this.set = function( name ) {
    this.name = name; <-- this
  }
}
```

How would I write the line so that I can assign the parameter to the private variable? Unlike Java, "this" also points to a function, so I can't figure it out.

Comment: `this` doesn't point to a function. You've provided an incomplete and invalid code example so it's hard to know exactly what you need, but one problem is that the `name` parameter is shadowing the `name` variable. Another is that you're not setting the variable; you're setting a property on some object referenced by `this`.

Comment: Are you using the outer function as a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

2020 edit:

I happen to come back to this question and realized that I was mistaken.
Better code example.

```
type = function() {
    var name = "default";
    var self = this;

    this.set = function(name) {
        console.log("this: " + this);
        console.log("self: " + self);
        console.log("name: " + name);
        name = name; // <-- name shadowed
    }

    this.get = function() {
        return name;
    }
}

test = new type();
console.log("test.name: " + test.name);
console.log("test.get: " + test.get());

test.set("new")
console.log("test.name: " + test.name);
console.log("test.get: " + test.get());
```

I wanted to avoid name shadowing which can be done in Java by doing

```
this.name = name;
```

However, in Javascript, "name" is declared as a public property and initialized so that defeats the purpose of this thought-exercise.
"self" technique won't work either (this is where I mistakenly thought it would work)

The true answer is Aadit M Shah's comment in the first answer.

With the recent EcmaScript (or not so recent), Javascript lets you assign getter and setter to a property, so this technique is probably not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You'll just have to use a different name for the argument so it won't shadow the private variable `name` outside the function `set`, that's all.

```js
var SomeClass = function() {
  var name;
  this.set = function( otherName ) { // argument should have a different name so it won't shadow the other variable "name"
    name = otherName;
  }
  this.get = function() {
    return name;
  }
};

var ins = new SomeClass();
ins.set("Jim Carrey");  // OK
console.log(ins.get()); // OK
console.log(ins.name);  // undefined as expected
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the function **set**, inner `name` variable will get more preference than the outer `name` variable. In order to assign some value to the outer variable, you will have to have a different name inside or outside.
However, You can do something like,

```
function() {
  this.name = '';
  this.set = function( name ) {
    this.name = name; <-- this
  }
}
```

This is not assigning the new value to the private variable, this is assigning the value to the object's property.

Comment: I like this answer more because I can keep the name, which best describes the variable while showing the different owner.

Comment: What? This answer makes no sense! Your never initializing the variable `name` declared on line 2. Furthermore, your `self` variable is the same as `this`. How is that any different from the code that the OP provided?

Comment: Correct @AaditMShah, This would have made more sense
`function() {
  this.name = '';
  this.set = function( name ) {
    this.name = name; <-- this
  }
}`

Comment: However, the OP wants to initialize a private variable. If you assign `name` to `this.name` then it wouldn't be private. What you really want to do is `function () { var hidden = {}; this.set = function (name) { hidden.name = name; }; }`.